# Using Javascript events with ASP.net AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I can't believe that this hasn't been covered before, but I have been having a hard time finding an answer to this one on Google.

I am learning AJAX with ASP.NET, and I have a working prototype.  My only problem is that I want to kick off my AJAX validation on a JavaScript event (onKeyUp to be exact) however, ASP.NET seems to only support its server side events for its version of AJAX.  How do I call my AJAX from a client side event?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Just wanted to add that I did find this trick out there, but this causes the website to do a postback, which makes no sense to me if your trying to do AJAX.

```
txtFirstName.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp","__doPostBack('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFirstName','')");
```

Comment: What exactly are you validating? Form fields or something else on the client side? Or are you validating the data being passed by your AJAX code on the server side?

Also just curious; are you working on an MVC app or Web Forms?

Comment: I want to validate what has been entered in a textbox against the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing Web Forms stuff and you want to validate some content as its being typed or at least after they submit the data.

You might want to take a look at the ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit. You can download the .dll and add it as a reference to your project.

Take a look at the [ValidatorCallOut](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx)

Comment: If you don't want to use Microsofts toolkit stuff and you want to do something more customized you might want to look into UpdatePanels and [partial postbacks](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax)

Comment: And to more directly answer your question the "trick" you found is on the right path. You want to do that sort of in conjunction with a partial postback and not a full post back. [See here](http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/trigger-partial-postback-from-javascript/)

Comment: I think I found an even better way to do this.  Instead of doing any kind of post back, I ignored .NET all together for this portion of my ajax.  I just wrote a javascript function to call a server side page for validation and added it to the onkeyUp event.  I will post some code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I "Borrowed" this code from w3Schools.com, So I want to give them credit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function val() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("spnFirstName").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "server.aspx", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
    //xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford"); //This is if you want to send values
  }
</script>



First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtFirstName_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" onkeyup="Val()"></asp:TextBox>
<span id="spnFirstName" runat="server" style="color:Red"> </span>
```

Server.aspx is an empty page that just has the word "Hello" in it.  As you can see, I tied this simple javascript function to the onKeyUp Event.  This also seems not to interfer with the ASP.NET AJAX validation.

I like doing this much better than adding a dll, because as long as I stick with the core asp.net product, I don't have to worry about other developers having to dig up libraries they might not have.